# How to test RoleEnvironment.Changing event on Azure local emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

How can I locally test the [RoleEnvironment.Changing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event using the Azure SDK 1.7? Which file do I have to change and do I have to run any other command after that file is changed?

The information on this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/badfb9b0-9aa4-48d9-908b-2fb8dc36f9e3) is not very complete and it doesn't work on 1.7 anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trial and error I discovered that the problem was the wrong cscfg. To test it:

1. Change the ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg from the Azure project
2. Open the Windows Azure SDK Environment as an Administrator
3. Change the Directory (cd) to the Azure project where the ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg file is located
4. run the command **csrun /update:[DEPLOYMENT ID];ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg** where [DEPLOYMENT ID] is the number in parenthesis following the label deployment (XX) of the Azure Emulator

Comment: I've found that the role will always restart the first time you run the command, but from then on your commands will not restart the role. Therefore, you should always start the role without the debugger attached, otherwise it will stop and destroy the role instead of restarting it.

Answer (score 3):

Also I noticed that the csrun /update:[DEPLOYMENT ID];ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg will terminate the deployment if we are debugging the solution (Start Debugging - F5), it will work normally only with (**Start without Debugging - Ctrl F5**) option.

Added just in case it helps anyone.